# "matches" filter not working on ip.addr in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I want to filter a bunch of IP addresses, and I expected this to work:

```
ip.addr matches "^1\.2\.3\.[0-9]+$"
```

There really seem to be two problems here:

1. ip.addr will never work with `matches`, no matter what you type in
2. The regex above is wrong for some reason

When searching for this problem, I found multiple mentions of doing something like `1.2.3.0/8` to specify the number of bits to match, but no explanation sufficient for me to use that.